# Solve the differential equation : $0.5 \frac{dy}{dx}=4.9-0.1y^2$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> The question is to solve the differential equation :
>
> $$0.5 \frac{dy}{dx}=4.9-0.1y^2$$

---

What I have attempted:

$$0.5 \frac{dy}{dx}=4.9-0.1y^2$$

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{4.9-0.1y^2}{0.5} $$

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = 9.8 - 0.2y^2 $$

$$ \int \frac{1}{9.8 - 0.2y^2} dy = \int 1 dx $$

$$ \int \frac{10}{98 - 2y^2} dy = \int 1 dx $$

$$ \int \frac{5}{49 - y^2} dy = \int 1 dx $$

$$ \int \frac{1}{49 - y^2} dy = \int \frac{1}{5} dx $$

How should I continue?

**EDIT** Thanks @andrenicolas for the hint

By using partial fractions

$$ \int \frac{1}{(7-y)(7+y)} dy = \int \frac{1}{5} dx $$

$$ \frac{1}{14}\int \frac{1}{7-y} + \frac {1}{7+y} dy = \int \frac{1}{5} dx $$

$$ \frac{1}{14} [ ln |y+7| - ln|y-7| ] =  \frac{x}{5} + c$$

$$ [ ln |y+7| - ln|y-7| ] = \frac{14x}{5} + 14c $$

$$ ln\frac{y+7}{y-7} = \frac{14x}{5} + 14c $$

$$ \frac{y+7}{y-7} = Ae^{\frac{14x}{5}} $$ (Letting $A = 14c$)

$$ y + 7 = yAe^{\frac{14x}{5}} - 7Ae^{\frac{14x}{5}} $$

$$ 7Ae^{\frac{14x}{5}} + 7 = yAe^{\frac{14x}{5}} - y $$

$$ 7Ae^{\frac{14x}{5}} + 7 = y(Ae^{\frac{14x}{5}} - 1) $$

$$ y = \frac{7Ae^{\frac{14x}{5}}}{(Ae^{\frac{14x}{5}} - 1)} $$

Comment: Do you know any trig substitutions that might be helpful?

Comment: Partial fractions.

Comment: @Mattos Not that I know off .. I solved it using partial fractions but was wondering what trig sub could I have used?

Comment: @dydxx Try $y = 7 \sin (t)$.. You will end up integrating $\sec (t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing your calculations

$$ \int \frac{1}{49 - y^2} dy = \int \frac{1}{5} dx $$

$$  \int \frac{1}{7^2 - y^2} dy = \int \frac{1}{5} dx $$

$$  \int \frac{1}{7 - y} + \frac{1}{7 + y} dy = \int \frac{14}{5} dx $$

$$ \log(\frac{7+y}{7-y}) = \frac{14}{5} x + C$$